# Simple probability problem with negation

Tags: probability

> A survey in a high school conducted that from 417 students 186 is doing sports, 136 music and 74 music and sports. What is the probability that randomly chosen student doesn't play sports and doesn't play music?

Isn't this just $\frac{21}{417} \cdot 100 = 5.03597122$ since the number of people that doesn't do anything is $417-(186+136+74)=21?$ I keep questioning my self right now...

Comment: But I feel like I'm over counting here. Am I not?

Comment: If $74$ is part of $186$ and $136$ then yes but it is not clear from the question. I interpreted otherwise.

Comment: If it is other interpretation, it will be $417 - (136 + 186 - 74)$.

Comment: I read it again and I think likely interpretation is what I wrote just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest in these sorts of problems to separate the students into disjoint groups. Let $w$ be the number of students who do neither music nor sports, $x$ the number of students who do music only, $y$ the number of students who do sports only, and $z$ the number who do both music and sports. These four groups are mutually exclusive, so we have

$$ w + x + y + z = 417 \Rightarrow w = 417 - (x + y + z) . $$

We also know from the given information that

$$ x + z = 136 , $$

$$ y + z = 186 , $$

$$ z = 74 . $$

Combining these three equations, we have

$$ (x + z) + (y + z) - z = 136 + 186 - 74 $$
$$ \Rightarrow x + y + z = 136 + 186 - 74 = 248 $$

Then, $w = 417 - (x + y + z) = 417 - 248 = 169 $.

As a percentage, we have

$$\frac{169}{417} \approx 40.5\% .$$